# How is a mis-named folder a hack attempt?

Tags: php, linux, apache

My website is entirely written by me in php on notepad, no WordPress or the like.  The only known weakness is that due to a complicated hardware situation, I can not use HTTPS for the login area.  It runs on a shared hosting account at iPage.  It's 'LAMP'.

I am setup to monitor reasons why the 404 page is called.  This is where my concern comes.  Someone is making attempts on folders in all lower case.  This more alarming because these folders words are in the login area sometimes.  For example, if I have a file at /loginArea/myHidden/index.php these odd requests are aimed at /myhidden for some reason.  Notice no caps and lack of the first directory.  This has been happening at a rate of one per day, from random IP addresses all around the world.  You might assume this was a coding mistake on my part at first, but I am 100% certain that has been ruled out by now.  They are moving around my folder structure, poking like they are searching for something.

They seem to be limited to folder words they could sniff from http traffic of logged in users.  They have not hit one that is known only to me.

No damage seems to have been done, but I am getting DAILY attempts and want to know what they are hoping for.

Comment: They may be trying to bypass case-sensitive rules for directory listing exclusions on your webserver, and obtain a file on a case-insensitive file system.

Comment: This is called [Security by Obscurity](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44094/isnt-all-security-through-obscurity) and you're finding one of the drawbacks: random guessing via brute force

Comment: @paddy, can you post a link for more info?

Comment: @Machavity, it's not random is the scary part, they know my words.  The good news is I am not relying on obscurity.  Just surprised how dedicated they are at something.

Comment: And about obscurity, my scripts all require a log-in check before they execute.  It's not like knowing the directory is the same as logging in.

Comment: I don't have a link.  I was just making a guess at what might be happening.  If you are concerned, you could add some simple log monitoring and temporarily block any IP that is doing repeated probes.  You work out how many probes is considered a hack, within what timeframe, and how long to block.  Repeated probes after lifting a block can induce a more severe block.  Use basic `iptables` rules or similar.  Maybe there's stuff out there for this already.

Comment: @paddy, Thanks.  I see what you mean for systems that ban directory browsing on just specific directories.  That's an excellent idea.  Still not sure why they don't use the full path.  Too bad they use a new IP each time.

Comment: Well, when they _stop_ doing it, at least you know to start finding the security hole ;-)  As for the new IP, they are probably using a Tor network or similar.